# SSRS and Google spreadsheets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am writing a report and one of the sources resides in a Google docs spreadsheet.  Is it possible to use that spreadsheet as a datasource in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Is this doc spreadsheet Excel file? If so , you can use ODBC driver and use the Excel file as data source. See:

http://hussain-msbi.blogspot.com/2012/07/create-ssrs-report-using-excel-data.html

Otherwise you have to custom a data process extension so that SSRS can read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use a google docs spreadsheet as a direct datasource for SSRS. You would need to make use of an API to download your data locally into a flat file format (such as csv). From there you can access the flat file as an SSRS datasource